# Extract values from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I need to extract values from an array of hashes:

```
data =
[{:diaria_media=>"103.58908136482939632545931759", 
  :room_night=>"1143",
  :valor_periodo=>"118402.320000"},   
 {:diaria_media=>"307.46792079207920792079207921", 
  :room_night=>"101",
  :valor_periodo=>"31054.260000"},
 {:diaria_media=>"313.000000",
  :room_night=>"9",
  :valor_periodo=>"2817.000000"},
 {:diaria_media=>"0.0",
  :room_night=>"7",
  :valor_periodo=>"0.0"},
 {:diaria_media=>"4.4630434782608695652173913043",
  :room_night=>"414",
  :valor_periodo=>"1847.700000"},
 {:diaria_media=>"150.89382627422828427853553482",
  :room_night=>"1393",
  :valor_periodo=>"210195.100000"}, 
 {:diaria_media=>"221.11425992779783393501805054",
  :room_night=>"554",
  :valor_periodo=>"122497.300000"},
 {:diaria_media=>"36.919200",
  :room_night=>"25",
  :valor_periodo=>"922.980000"},
 {:diaria_media=>"31.967530864197530864197530864",
  :room_night=>"81",
  :valor_periodo=>"2589.370000"},
 {:diaria_media=>"0",
  :room_night=>"0",
  :valor_periodo=>"0.000000"}]
```

I need to get all the `:room night` fields and add the values. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use formatting to make your question's text more readable. Readability helps us help you, and it helps those in the future searching for a similar solution. Grammar and readability are very important on Stack Overflow and not taking the time to do your best, to put good effort into the question, turns off many who would normally want to help. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ along with links in that page as it explains it all well.

Comment: I heavily edited the question to focus on the actual problem the OP needs to solve.

Comment: @taiuan-pagini what's the status on your question?

Answer (score -1):

first: it's not nice to ask for help and to format the question as you did.
second: the question has nothing to do with Rails or with Savon.
This is a pure Ruby question.
The solution seems simple to me.
You iterate over your array and summarize the numbers for each key :room_night
For example like this:

```
nights = 0
data.each do |booking|
    nights += booking[:room_night].to_i
end
print "nights=#{nights}\n"
```

If you go functional it's even more simple:

```
nights = data.map{|e| e[:room_night].to_i}.reduce(:+)
```

and done!

As a bonus I put a executable script into Pastbin https://pastebin.com/29nMTYrK